# mostrar valores de un metodo en otro metodo con php orientado a objetos

Tags: php, mysql, método

Buenas, estoy trabajando con php orientado a objetos, entonces tengo una clase y dos métodos, en el primer método tengo un `foreach` donde extraigo unos valores de la base de datos

```
public function ambitosController(){

        $respuesta = gestorOposicionesModels::ambitosModel("amb_oposiciones");

        foreach($respuesta as $row => $item){

        echo '<option value="'.$item["titulo"].'">'.$item["titulo"].'</option>';

        }
}
```

Y para el otro método donde me gustaría que apareciera lo que trae el método ya mencionado, estoy haciendo otro `foreach` pero en una parte me gustaría que me mostrara el valor del primer método.

No se me ocurre nada, ya intenté invocando el método de la siguiente manera:

```
$categoria = self::categoriasController();
```

Pero me muestra los resultados fuera de donde me gustaria que me los mostrara..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que llamas a **categoriasController** mediante **self::**, el invocar un método mediante self se realiza **cuando llamas a una constante definida o a un método estático**. De lo contrario deberías llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->categoriasController();
```

En el caso que no sea este el problema, deberías explicar un poco más el problema o bien mostrar la clase entera para poder ver que ocurre, ya que no se entiende muy bien el problema "*me muestra los resultados fuera de donde me gustaría que me los mostrara*".

EDICIÓN: Además comentar, que un método no debería finalizar con **echo** (de ahí quizás que te muestre el valor donde no quieres), las funciones han de finalizar con un **return**, esto no quiere decir que vaya a generar un error, pero es lo recomendable. Un ejemplo bien realizado de tu método:

```
public function ambitosController(){
    $respuesta = gestorOposicionesModels::ambitosModel("amb_oposiciones");

    $res = '';
    foreach($respuesta as $row => $item){
        $res .= '<option value="'.$item["titulo"].'">'.$item["titulo"].'</option>';
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchas gracias me funciono, cambie el echo por el return como tu colocaste y listo problema solucionado, eso si para mostrarlo coloco, echo gestorOposicion::ambitosController(); asi lo tengo que colocar ? o hay otra manera?

Comment: Efectivamente hay que hacer el echo para imprimir el resultado, pero recuerda que ambitosController no es un método estático, por lo que para acceder a el se debe hacer mediante this->ambitosController() ( a no ser que estés haciendo herencia de clases, en cuyo caso bastaría con parent::metodo